# Better Rails code for update or create clause?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

The code smells and i'm sure i'm missing a helper to do a simple 
update or create query like the below snippet :

```
  @user_answer = current_user.user_answers.find_by_question_id(params[:a_question])
  if @user_answer.nil?
    @user_answer = current_user.user_answers.build({ :answer_id => params[:an_answer] , :question_id => params[:a_question] })      
    @user_answer.save  
  else
    @user_answer.update_attributes(:answer_id => params[:an_answer])
    @user_answer.save 
  end
```

Comment: just a small suggestion, you don't need to call on save method in the else block as update_attributes will anyway save the object implicitly. Please see my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be looking for the `find_or_initialize_by` method. For example:

```
@user_answer = current_user.user_answers.find_or_initialize_by_question_id(params[:a_question])
@user_answer.answer_id = params[:an_answer]
@user_answer.save
```

Comment: Also we can do a find_or_create_by_question_id, so that will avoid the save here.

Comment: @ManjunathManohar The reason I suggested `find_or_initialize_by` is that the poster wants to update the `answer_id` regardless of whether the `user_answer` exists or not. If it _does_ exist, `find_or_create_by` will not actually update the record. It will find and leave it as is, so he would still need to manually set the `answer_id` and call `save` or use `update_attribute(s!)`. Creating the record first and then updating in this way would require an unnecessary extra db call.

Answer (score 0):

How about,

```
@user_answer = current_user.user_answers.find_or_create_by_question_id(params[:a_question])
```

This will avoid the explicit save